# Как передать переменную в класс?

Tags: c#, классы, переменные

Ситуация такая. В Main я вызываю следующие код:

```
new GeneratedCode.WordGen().CreatePackage(@"D:\Temp\Output.docx", foo, ZAKAZCHIK);
```

В классе WordGen вызывается метод CreatePackage, который вызывает метод CreateParts, в котором вызывается GenerateMainDocumentPart1Content.
Вопрос как мне ZAKAZCHIK передать в метод GenerateMainDocumentPart1Content ?

Как передать в CreatePackage понятно, но он мне не нужен. Напрямую нужный метод из main мне нельзя.

```
 public void CreatePackage(string filePath, string foo, string ZAKAZCHIK)
    {
        using(WordprocessingDocument package = WordprocessingDocument.Create(filePath, WordprocessingDocumentType.Document))
        {
            CreateParts(package);
        }

    }

     private void CreateParts(WordprocessingDocument document)
    {
        ExtendedFilePropertiesPart extendedFilePropertiesPart1 = document.AddNewPart<ExtendedFilePropertiesPart>("rId3");
        GenerateExtendedFilePropertiesPart1Content(extendedFilePropertiesPart1);
        }
        }

         private void GenerateMainDocumentPart1Content(MainDocumentPart mainDocumentPart1)
    {
```

Comment: Ну добавьте методам `CreateParts` и `GenerateMainDocumentPart1Content` еще по одному параметру `string ZAKAZCHIK` и передавайте. Или, что мне кажется сомнительным, сделайте поле класса, в `CreatePackage` присваивайте ему значение из `ZAKAZCHIK`, а в `GenerateMainDocumentPart1Content` берите из него значение

Comment: Ради всего святого, `customer`, а не `ZAKAZCHIK`!

Answer (score 1):

Предложу такой вариант:

Добавить в класс свойство `Customer`

```
public class WordGen
{
    string Customer {private get; private set;}
    //ваш код
}
```

Тогда в метод

```
public void CreatePackage(string filePath, string foo, string customer)
{
//можно добавить
Customer=customer;
//и дальше ваш код
}
```

(при условии, что `private void GenerateMainDocumentPart1Content` - член `WordGen`)

в `GenerateMainDocumentPart1Content` вам будет доступно свойство `Customer`.

**UPD**. Полагаю, что логичнее было бы использовать даже поле, а не свойство.

Answer (score 0):

```
public void CreatePackage(string filePath, string foo, string ZAKAZCHIK)
{
    using(WordprocessingDocument package = WordprocessingDocument.Create(filePath, WordprocessingDocumentType.Document))
    {
        CreateParts(package,ZAKAZCHIK);
    }

}

 private void CreateParts(WordprocessingDocument document, string ZAKAZCHIK)
{
    ExtendedFilePropertiesPart extendedFilePropertiesPart1 = document.AddNewPart<ExtendedFilePropertiesPart>("rId3");
    GenerateExtendedFilePropertiesPart1Content(extendedFilePropertiesPart1,ZAKAZCHIK);
    }
    }

     private void GenerateMainDocumentPart1Content(MainDocumentPart mainDocumentPart1, string ZAKAZCHIK)
{
```

Comment: или определить параметр ZAKAZCHIK в начале описания класса

public class Test1
{
  private string ZAKAZCHIK;
  
  
  public void CreatePackage(string filePath, string foo, string ZAKAZCHIK)
{
  ZAKAZCHIK = ZAKAZCHIK;
   //some code
}


//somr method

 private void GenerateMainDocumentPart1Content(MainDocumentPart mainDocumentPart1)
{
   vat t1 = this.ZAKAZCHIK;
  //some code
}


}